# SELECT and UPDATE statements one after other

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency

I am working on an Online Booking System. In a normal process when a user selects a room which was marked as 'Available' at a particular time and submits his choice. Now at back-end, just to confirm, I run a SELECT statement to verify the room's status is available or not as follows:

```
SELECT room_status FROM rooms WHERE room_number = 'XXX'
```

then I run a UPDATE query to mark it as 'UNAVAILABLE':

```
UPDATE rooms SET room_status = 'UNAVAILABLE' WHERE room_number = 'XXX' AND room_status = 'AVAILABLE'
```

Now when I ran SELECT query, the room was available and as I proceed to UPDATE query, the room is taken by other user. So the UPDATE query will fail. I want the room to be taken by first user only. What should I do ?

UPDATE: There can also be a case when a user has to book multiple rooms. For instance user selects 8 rooms. My code was at 4th room checking its status and as it reached 8th room the first room is gone. Also it may happen, while I was checking 4th room and upto now 8th room is gone.

I am using : PHP and MySQL

Comment: Perhaps you could flag the room as 'LOCKED' just after you run the select statement

Comment: @gbestard I have updated my post. Please have a look for another case which is missed initially.

Comment: Is there really a time gap between checking that the room is available and booking it? If so, how much time?

Comment: @MarcusAdams There isn't any time gap between the two as such. These are two loops basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When selecting the rows, you need to lock them, so that other queries can't read or write from them until you finish updating them. In MySQL, this can be done inside a transaction using the [SELECT ... FOR UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) statement:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT room_status FROM rooms WHERE room_number = 'XXX' FOR UPDATE;
```

All the rows returned from the previous statement will be locked until the end of the current transaction. You can now mark them as unavailable:

```
UPDATE rooms SET room_status = 'UNAVAILABLE' WHERE room_number = 'XXX';
```

Remember to close the transaction by commiting the changes. This will release the lock on the rows.

```
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thanks. One more question: lets say the room is gone before running the SELECT statement. So the SELECT query will result empty result. In this case I want to release the locks over rows. Should I use COMMIT or ROLLBACK ?

Comment: Your application code wouldn't run the update query if the select returns 0 rows. Since you didn't write to the db, you can then use either COMMIT or ROLLBACK to close the transaction. I'd prefer COMMIT in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I find that on `Insert`, `Update` and `Delete` you need to add `with NC` (no commit) to the end of the statement, otherwise it doesn't work.

That will hopefully fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, submit the `UPDATE` first:

```
UPDATE rooms
SET room_status = 'UNAVAILABLE'
WHERE room_number = 'XXX' AND room_status = 'AVAILABLE'
```

Then check the number of affected rows. If the number of affected rows is 1, then you successfully booked the room.

If anyone else submits the exact same query, only one will succeed.